# How to read numbers in scientific notation in R

Tags: r, floating-point

I want to read a data file into R. The data format is `4e20.5` in Fortran style.

```
         -0.12652E-03         0.18851E-03         0.91379E-04         0.20404E-04
```

If possible, please show me how to get the numbers with `read.table` function. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Scientific notation is fully supported in R. For instance, `x<- -0.12652E-03` works. To read a file written by a fortran code, use `read.fortran`.

Comment: I think your problem originates in the spacing between the numbers. How are the numbers separated? Use the `sep` argument.

Comment: Could any one give me example code for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer rather than a comment for formatting reasons:  if your file *really* has just this text, `read.table()` should work fine (as pointed out in the comments), e.g.:

```
read.table(text=" -0.12652E-03         0.18851E-03         0.91379E-04         0.20404E-04")
##            V1         V2         V3         V4
## 1 -0.00012652 0.00018851 9.1379e-05 2.0404e-05
```

All we can do is speculate that there is something odd about the separators in your file.  Without a link to the file, we probably can't do more than speculate.

Note that the print formatting has changed (e.g. -0.12652E-03 is now printed as -0.00012652), but the numbers are read correctly (see `?options` and search for `scipen`).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The first try error make me thought that R cannot read numbers in scientifice notation.

Answer (score 0):

Plz forgive my ignorance with R. Now I resolve this problem:

```
 data <- read.fwf("data.txt",width=rep(20,4))
```